# Using Python to find a global maximum from array of variables and functional values

Tags: python, function, scipy, mathematical-optimization, maximize

In the case of my problem, I have a dataset with a function dependent on 4 variables. The dataset is in the form of an array whose rows have 5 columns, where columns 0,1,2,3 are input values and column 4 contains the output. I want to find the location and value of the global maxima of the manifold defined by the input values. In particular, this dataset has several local maxima which are not of interest.

I am new to using python which is making things a little difficult, especially because when using libraries like scipy it is necessary to define a functional form prior to throwing random values and initiating a search for minima/maxima. If anyone has ideas for a library or a specific technique I could use, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? Is it a numpy array?

Comment: what's "the manifold"? do you just want to the global max of the 4th column?

Comment: @RodrigoDorantes-Gilardi Yes, it is a numpy array. It has been difficult to start to be honest, because I have no idea of the functional form. Specifically, I am failing to wrap my head around how to throw guess values, etc. for a usual maximization technique to work given that I do not know the form.

Comment: @PaulH What I meant by manifold is, given a large enough number of (x,y) and f(x,y) values (as a 3D example), the input variables define some sort of plane. Here, I have 4 input variables that are defining some sort of function in 5D space, whose global maxima and location of maxima I need.

Comment: look at `numpy.argmax`

Comment: Wouldn't that only provide the first occurrence of the largest value in the functional value column? I'm looking for a maximization routine whereby, after looking at, say, a million datapoints that are the 4 coordinates that define a point on a manifold, the routine will then find the global maximum/minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `dataset` is a numpy ndarray of shape (n, 4),

```
import numpy as np
global_maxima = dataset[np.argmax(dataset[:,-1])][:-1]
```

will give you the global maxima over the first three columns which if I understood well are your input columns. If you want the global minimum replace `np.argmax` by `np.argmin`.

Comment: Hi @Rodrigo! This would only return the maximum value of a coordinate as seen in those columns. What I'm looking for, as mentioned in a previous comment, is a maximization routine that spits out 4 coordinates corresponding to the location of the global maximum of the function.

Comment: Yes! This is fast and makes sense since the values it's putting out satisfy my crosschecks for a maximum. 
I am still wondering if there's some optimization technique (along the lines of SGD or something similar) that can be constructed to extract coordinates of global maxima provided an n-dimensional set of coordinates of a multivariate function. Or is that just overkill?

And shoudl I reframe my original question to make it clearer in any way?